# Strange typescript error when using typescript generics nested

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, typescript-generics

So, i'm working on some typescript code and i found this weird bug that i don't know why it happens. I'm just starting with the language so it might be a newbie question but anyway, this is really strange to me.

First thing first [i have a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAUNaAzAlqohAIQBccSqAYoSMQNzbTwAOALvvAHakUIoQAeQ5deAHnYALfBAB8TAL6ZMoSDAGoA6vmnwAruwCS3FAA8MzAkT6VBtG0xxtOPW5uGi3OvYZPnJGXklFTUoO21dKX9kMwA5eGNuACEAJzBgAGtkdhgsHGt6dyoQByKnFi9ecgjPV14EpLSM7PZA2QVMZVVwcIBVCGRU6Fj2ZFMNEssCumJoAF5pnGgwCjLEABUAT1ZkCAA6ZKEhABlmZQB6C%20Wb27u7gDVoAFpoLSktgH4V02gpeAA7tB2PBoBB4CAAG7IaC6T7MFxiCD8EoieoQdryBZLHD4UyxPYUADa%20Vu%20m4%20AAjvpkBR2KkaQAaZg3QrEYkAcjAHIAuizoIo%20ThlN0wjABkMfP8-PiLKNxnMPFKDElzEs2TBFqScKtoOttrsDkdTudMFd7hbLVboE9XhsgtAAfBUpkIIzHR9Pl7vgBNAzQTLcQEesDsDkwCD0sDcADmyHdumgACt9JHoIgeBz2I7nZloAAjZDAMCpmEeGIWWQ-aBCfNJovZlAEbjIRCw7gYZTOKrI2popHKmUBaQdbGkkWhXriwapKUVxomZpZHIweUTWpz2ULlLpZe5dWzTU4lZrWYGvaHY5nYVm67W%20-W23QACCMHwYLA%20EQ7oBH2BDqdF0IE%20d17SrDM9m4LNoAAWzAbIwXGQZgVBGDkARHsUUEfs3G3JdWkxOQx1NbpzWeciKMo8joA2H0AAUAFEAGUXiotjKMwcZ9BgvUzx2PYlgAYQACWfAAlbEORE8SOWZHBjROSSFNk5gjDiDZJLUjYOS6FR2H42oK3EWARjMMZ1w8IitWYckqRpOkGXQmYbAoAAKbItngXA4CJAAiDVfJ5ABKIk%20W6fTdkM2U9jw3cCJMtdFRKTdzFiloVys6B3OQTzvNgPyAuC0K9IMoRUhQVI8RjIRcA8HCJASsyFUmQRoAAHw3KIVQrdrOukedEkXOKMuxDyvJ8-zD0CtrmDG7z0GgIlqHbAMcvG-LJpsQKVhgZbEojekqugb4AANngAEnQahFBO6AKBbaFUh5O7oAARm6TAIrLVEezSvdjNM8yksEFLYj%201osWs3FouArDUArGLBp3dK2lgORQoqZ0Kqqz4KDK7HYxquqe2M9GeRCT6DOJ9FB1VWIAf2vrpTpsxMtJLGhhxvHys5wnap%209FSYx3Svr7EnGqBlrUDZ5g8XMPZcaigI0eF5wecq2NFfx3nqv57DxbJinRY8dYj1JIk2QoSMNZjHlTyIc8IF0oA) so you guys can iterate on it to help me on solving it

Anyway, so here is the code i'm working on, just an example:

```js
class Model {
  fields!: ModelFields;
  options!: ModelOptions<this>;
}

class ModelWithoutIndex {
  fields!: ModelFields;
  options!: ModelOptionsWithoutIndex<this>;
}

class ModelWithIndexNotInBrackets {
  fields!: ModelFields;
  options!: ModelOptionsNotInBracket<this>;
}

class User extends Model {
  fields = {
    a: FieldTypes.BOOL
  }
//                        V - Why? and how to solve it?
  options: ModelOptions<this> = {
    indexes: [{
      unique: true,
      fields: ['a']
    }]
  }
}

class UserWithoutIndex extends ModelWithoutIndex {
  fields = {
    a: FieldTypes.BOOL
  }
//                                   V - This works, why???? You know what's strange, it just don't work because ModelIndex is an Object defined in {}
  options: ModelOptionsWithoutIndex<this> = {
  }
}

class UserWithIndexNotInBrackets extends ModelWithIndexNotInBrackets {
  fields = {
    a: FieldTypes.BOOL
  }
//                                   V - As i said, why this works?, This doesn't make sense to me
  options: ModelOptionsNotInBracket<this> = {
  }
}

// ------------ TYPES ----------------
enum FieldTypes {
  CHAR = 'CHAR',
  BOOL = 'BOOL',
  INT = 'INT'
}

type ModelIndex<M extends Model> = {
  unique: true
  fields: (keyof M["fields"])[]
}

type ModelIndexesNotInBracket<M extends ModelWithIndexNotInBrackets> = (keyof M["fields"])[]

type OrderingOfModelOptions<M extends Model | ModelWithoutIndex | ModelWithIndexNotInBrackets> = keyof M["fields"]|
  keyof { [F in keyof M["fields"] as F extends string ? `-${F}` : never] : 1}


type ModelOptionsNotInBracket<M extends ModelWithIndexNotInBrackets> = {
  indexes?: ModelIndexesNotInBracket<M>[];
  ordering?: OrderingOfModelOptions<M>[];
}

type ModelOptionsWithoutIndex<M extends ModelWithoutIndex> = {
  ordering?: OrderingOfModelOptions<M>[];
}
type ModelOptions<M extends Model> = {
  indexes?: ModelIndex<M>[];
  ordering?: OrderingOfModelOptions<M>[];
}

type ModelFields = {
  [field: string]: FieldTypes
}
```

As i was debugging i saw that `ModelIndex` actually is passed as `ModelIndex<M & Model>` but this is not what i want, what i want is `ModelIndex<M>`, i don't know and i don't understand why typescript does this automatic intersection.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you try to reduce this further to give a [mre]?  There's an awful lot of stuff going on in that code, and if you can make it more minimal, it will be easier to investigate.

Comment: If your question is really just "why does this happen", it's because, `this` is considered an implicitly generic subtype of the current class (so in `Model`, `this` is going to be some *subtype* of `Model`).  And your `ModelIndex<T>` type uses `keyof T['xxx']`, and `keyof` is *contravariant* in its argument, so if `X extends Y` then `keyof Y extends keyof X` and not necessarily vice versa.  Generics quickly become *invariant* and cannot be used in subtypes easily if you have complex type functions.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) for explanations of variance (co-, contra-, and in-).  I could write this up as an answer with more of an explanation, but I wonder if you think it would fully address the question.  If not, what is missing for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @jcalz, i've submitted an issue on github and it worked, it was really simple so solve, i submitted an answer here so it can help others with the same problem as me

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an issue and they responded me, types are not automatically asserted on class property initializers. You can see the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49851#issuecomment-1179751441) but i will also translate for others

> Your property fields has the type `{ a: FieldTypes }`, but your generic type `ModelOptions<>` requires the type argument to extend `Model`. But the type of `this` is `{ fields: { a: FieldTypes } }`, and it does not extend `Model` (which is `{ fields: ModelFields; options: ModelOptions<this> }`).

> When you type your property fields correctly it works:

```js
class User extends Model {
  fields: ModelFields = {
    a: FieldTypes.BOOL
  }
  // ...
}
```

> The type of re-defined properties is not inherited. This would require [#10570](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570).